# Error: 2.5e-1 cannot be used as a function

Tags: function

i wrote a simple program and i'm getting this error which i never encountered yet. Can you help me out?

line 13: error: 2.5e-1 cannot be used as a function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int dirac(int);

int main()
{
    float y;

    for(int k = 0; k <= 4; k++){
        y = 2*dirac(k)-0.5*dirac(k-1)*0.25(2*dirac(k-2)-0.5*dirac(k-3));


        cout << "k = " << k << ": ";
        cout << setw(8) << setfill(' ');
        cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << y << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int dirac(int x){
    if(x == 0){
        x = 1;
        return x;
    }else{
        x = 0;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    y = 2*dirac(k)-0.5*dirac(k-1)*0.25(2*dirac(k-2)-0.5*dirac(k-3));
                                      ^---
```

You probably forgot a `*` at the indicated spot.